# Using publish-composite with Angular-Meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I have two Collections `Articles` and `Categories` let's say their documents are like this

**Article**

```
{
   "_id": "blabla",
   "title" : "title",
   "description" : "description",
   "categoryId" : "catId"
}
```

**Category**

```
{
   "_id": "catId",
   "title" : "category",
   "description" : "description"
}
```

I want to make a subscription to make them like this

```
{
   "_id": "blabla",
   "title" : "title",
   "description" : "description",
   "category" : {
       "title" : "category",
       "description" : "description"
   }
}
```

I tried using [publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) and here it's my code.
**Server**

```
Meteor.publishComposite('articles', {
    find: function() {
        return Articles.find({}, { sort: {}, limit: 10 });
    },
    children: [
        {
            find: function(article) {
                return Categories.findOne({ _id: article.categoryId });
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

**And the client angularjs Controller is**

```
angular.module("dee").controller("ArticlesListCtrl", ['$scope', '$meteor', function($scope, $meteor){
    $scope.articles = $meteor.collection(Articles).subscribe('articles');
}]);
```

and the **view** is

```
{{ articles | json }}
```

the problem is it prints the article collection only without the relation.

Comment: Did you try nested ng-repeat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding to what @Deadly posted:

Publish composite makes it convenient to fetch related documents in a single subscription. How those documents are handled is still the same as if you made 2 separate subscriptions.

In your case, you would have two collections client side. One collection for Articles and one collection for Categories. Which Articles and which Categories that are in  your local collection is based on that subscription you made.

```
// get a subscription to 'articles'. Use $scope.$meteorCollection so
// the subscription is destroyed when the $scope is destroyed. If you don't you will end up carrying these collections on to anther page.
$scope.$meteorSubscribe('articles').then(function() {
    // This swill get you the articles from the local collection
    $scope.articles = $scope.$meteorCollection(Articles);

    // then you need to get the related Categories for the articles
    $scope.getCategories = function(article) {
        return $scope.$meteorObject(Categoris, article._id);
    }
});
```

Comment: What f i want to make this data transform from the server side instead of the client side ?

Comment: The subscription you created handles everything server side with one subscription because of publish composite. On the client side, you access that information the way suggested here. When you do `$scope.articles = $scope.$meteorCollection(Articles)` you are accessing the information sent to the client collection, not the server.

Answer (score 2):

Controller:

```
   angular.module("dee").controller("ArticlesListCtrl", ['$scope', '$meteor', function($scope, $meteor){
        $scope.articles = $scope.$meteorCollection(Articles).subscribe('articles');
        $scope.getCategory = function(article) {
            return $scope.$meteorObject(Categories, article._id);
        };
    }]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="article in articles" ng-init="category=getCategory(article)"></div>
```

I also know better way to do it, but it doesn't work with angular and looks like nobody cares about it https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/720

Comment: What f i want to make this data transform from the server side instead of the client side ?

Comment: You can transform your data on server in publish function, but in your case it's better to use my way.